# Kendo React PDF and changing from class component to function component

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, pdf-generation

I'm changing my class component to a function component and stuck on the render PDF. It was working fine in the class component. The Kendo docs only have a class component usage guide.

This component simply renders HTML and gives the user the option to download a PDF.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { PDFExport } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';
import { PdfButton } from 'components/StyledButtons';

import {
  Container,
  CircularProgress
} from '@material-ui/core';

function ViewProject({ _project, props }) {
  const exportBriefing = id => e => {
    this[id].save();
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {_project && (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <PdfButton onClick={exportBriefing(_project.id)} />
            <PDFExport
              pageTemplate={DocumentTemplate}
              paperSize={'A4'}
              margin="1.5cm"
              scale={0.7}
              fileName={'Project_Brief'}
              ref={r => (this[_project.id] = r)}
            >

              <---HTML content here--->

            </PDFExport>
        </Container>
      )}
      {!_project && (
        <CircularProgress />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ firestore: { ordered } }) => ({
  _project: ordered.project && ordered.project[0],
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(props => [
    { collection: 'projects', storeAs: 'project', doc: props.match.params.id },
  ])
)(ViewProject);
```

This is my error (where hY2MWyk4piTBjhpJDFIc is the 'id' of the doc):

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If you post the original class component, it might be easier to provide refactoring advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `useRef`hook, to declare your ref as null and then get the value :

```
  const myRef = useRef(null);
```

Then attach to the Component that you want to ref:

```
    <Fragment>
      {_project && (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <PdfButton onClick={exportBriefing(_project.id)} />
            <PDFExport
              pageTemplate={DocumentTemplate}
              paperSize={'A4'}
              margin="1.5cm"
              scale={0.7}
              fileName={ 'Project_Brief'}
              ref={ myRef}
            >
```

Check [this docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to get more info related to `useRef`:

Answer (score 0):

The `this` context of a functional component does not persist across renders.

You'll want to use the `useState` hook instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ricardo Gonzalez for pointing me in the right direction. I was overthinking this and using useRef straight from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) fixed the problem.

```
function ViewProject({ _project }) {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    inputEl.current.save();
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {_project && (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <StyledPaper>
            <PdfButton onClick={onButtonClick} />
            <PDFExport
              pageTemplate={DocumentTemplate}
              paperSize={'A4'}
              margin="1.5cm"
              scale={0.7}
              fileName={`Project_Brief: ${
                _project.project_number
                }`}
              ref={inputEl}
            >
```